# Snowflake stored procedure - while loop only iterates over first row in the table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
create or replace procedure "CS_DEV"."META".SP_DATA_RETENTION("Trgt_DB" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Schema" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Stage" VARCHAR(20))
returns string
language JavaScript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$

var select_stmt = `SELECT * FROM ` + Trgt_DB + `.META.PREPROCESS_META`;
    var select_stmt_sql = { sqlText: select_stmt };
    var select_stmt_create = snowflake.createStatement(select_stmt_sql);
    var select_stmt_exec = select_stmt_create.execute();`

while (select_stmt_exec.next()) {

   var TGT_SCHEMA_NAME = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(5);
   var TGT_TABLE_NAME = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(6);
   var retentt = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(13);
   var retentp = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(12);

   var remove_data_tbl = `delete from ` +TGT_SCHEMA_NAME+ `.` +TGT_TABLE_NAME+ ` A USING META.PREPROCESS_META B where A.SYS_DATE <= DATEADD('`+retentt+`', -`+retentp+`, current_date()) AND B.RETENTION_TYPE = '`+retentt+`' AND B.RETENTION_PERIOD = `+retentp+ ` AND B.TGT_SCHEMA_NAME = '`+TGT_SCHEMA_NAME+ `' AND B.TGT_TABLE_NAME = '` +TGT_TABLE_NAME+`'`;
        var remove_data_tbl_sql = {sqlText: remove_data_tbl }; 
        var remove_data_tbl_create = snowflake.createStatement(remove_data_tbl_sql); 
        var remove_details_exec = remove_data_tbl_create.execute();}
```

[image]

Running the first statement produces the table above and then TGT_SCHEMA_NAME, TGT_TABLE_NAME, RETENTION_TYPE, and RETENTION_PERIOD values are taken and iterated through, however the procedure will only iterate over the first row DIM_AIRLINES.

Comment: To ensure quote balance isn't an issue (because Stackoverflow uses quotes and so does the code and that can be difficult to get the formatting right sometimes), please confirm that the code looks right with the modified formatting. Don't worry about indentation, but the code and quote balance should represent what's going on with the code.

Comment: A couple of things to note. `var` defines a variable, so you don't want to redefine variables inside the loop. When you use backquotes to define a string in JavaScript, you can then use variables and expressions as template literals instead of closing the string and concatenating with `+`. In other words, you can use `delete from ${TGT_SCHEMA_NAME}.${TGT_TABLE_NAME}`... (I can't show that with backticks since that shows the code highlight at Stackoverflow.

Comment: Yeah the code looks correct thank you, I'll attempt without the concatenating + and try with the ${} instead

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly modified version. Can you run this and see its output? If it fails, look in the query history tab to see what SQL the procedure attempted to run. Then you can make adjustments as required. If you need more help post the error(s) you're getting when running the procedure and/or the SQL errors in the query history tab.

```
create or replace procedure "CS_DEV"."META".SP_DATA_RETENTION("Trgt_DB" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Schema" VARCHAR, "Trgt_Stage" VARCHAR(20))
returns string
language JavaScript
EXECUTE AS CALLER
as
$$

"option strict"

var sql = `SELECT * FROM ${Trgt_DB}.META.PREPROCESS_META`;
var rs = exec(sql);
var tgtSchemaName;
var tgtTableName;
var retentt;
var retentp;
var remove_data_tbl;

while (rs.next()) {

   tgtSchemaName = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(5);
   tgtTableName = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(6);
   retentt = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(13);
   retentp = select_stmt_exec.getColumnValue(12);

   remove_data_tbl = `delete from ${tgtSchemaName}.${tgtTableName} A USING META.PREPROCESS_META B
      where A.SYS_DATE <= DATEADD('$retentt', -${retentp}, current_date()) AND B.RETENTION_TYPE = '${retentt}' AND B.RETENTION_PERIOD = ${retentp} AND B.TGT_SCHEMA_NAME = '${tgtSchemaName}' AND B.TGT_TABLE_NAME = '${tgtTableName}'`;
   exec(remove_data_tbl);
}

// ---- End main function. Start of helper functions.

function exec(sql){
    cmd = {sqlText: sql};
    stmt = snowflake.createStatement(cmd);
    var rs;
    rs = stmt.execute();
    return rs;
}

$$;
```

Comment: Yeah the same situation happens, it only runs the first iteration of the table which is DIM_AIRLINES instead of iterating through each row of the table

Comment: I updated the code to return a value indicating how many times it went through the loop. If the result of the first select query has more than one row, it should go through the loop more than once or error.